# Wikipages empty after restore from backup

Tags: web-part, backup, restore, wiki-pages

We run our intranet on SharePoint 2010. We have several web applications and we use DocAve 5 to backup the content of our intranet. After a user reported that he had erroneously deleted a wiki page library we restored it using DocAve (5.7.0.0).

The library was a standard wiki page library, not the enterprise library. After the restore the wiki pages were empty (see table below). We also tried  an out-of-place restore of another site collection and the restore was OK, except the wiki page library. All the versions were visible  but they were all empty.

Did someone experience the same problem?  Has anybody found a solution?

**Details**
If we look at the pages we get this in the original state and the other after backup.

[image: Pages in original state]

[image: Pages after restore]

If we look at the source code of those two pages we notice the following. In a Wiki page the content is normally stored in the EmbeddedFormField control.

[image: ASP.NET code in original state.]

In the backup, that control is empty, hence the page is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was far more complex and had to do with the DocAve package. The vendor supplied a bugfix patch to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the library has been deleted in error by the user, can you not restore this from the collection recycle bin ?

Comment: Not really because the pages were deleted via WebDav. We went on restoring from DocAve because we couldn't find anything in the recycle bin (also the admin recycle bin).

Comment: The solution was far more complex and had to do with the DocAve package. The vendor supplied a bugfix patch to solve the problem.